# Flash Instance Variable Always null?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am building a Flex application with a problem I am having with detecting whether or not a variable has been initialized. Observe this simplified code sample:

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    private var pageObject:* = null; //Yes the "*" data type is needed ;)

  //Fired by the application elseware
    private function constructMenu(e:ResultEvent):void {
      if (this.pageObject != null) {
        //This block never runs...

        // The pageObject will be null when the application
        // first runs, so skip this first time around.
        // However... this method will be called multiple
        // times. Since FoodMenu() is a display object
        // and is instantiated below, all subsequent calls
        // to this method will require us to remove the old
        // display object before adding a new one.
      } else {
        // This block always runs...
      }

      setTimeout(function():void {
        this.pageObject = new FoodMenu(); //Should now be not-null!!!

        //Do more stuff with the FoodMenu() and add to the main application
      }, 1000);
    }
  ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Based on the given code sample and comments, could someone please explain why `this.pageObject` always registers as not null, regardless of how many times the `constructMenu()` method is called or how many times the `FoodMenu()` class is instantiated?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: the full MXML as requested

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           xmlns:components="components.*"
           xmlns:pagesservice="services.pagesservice.*"
           xmlns:menuservice="services.menuservice.*"
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" backgroundColor="0x141414"
           creationComplete="init(event)" skinClass="skins.Theme" xmlns:pages="components.pages.*" xmlns:reviewsservice="services.reviewsservice.*">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.asual.swfaddress.*;
        import com.forwardfour.boncuisson.events.MenuEvent;
        import com.greensock.TweenMax;
        import com.greensock.plugins.VisiblePlugin;

        import components.header.Menu;
        import components.pages.FoodMenu;

        import flash.utils.setTimeout;

        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.IVisualElement;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        import skins.Theme;

        import spark.components.Group;

    //Globalize a reference to the navigation menu
        private var menu:Menu;

    //Globalize a reference to the page content
        private var pageObject:* = null; //This reference will be various types, so just make a general object

    /**
     * Initialization
     * -------------------------------
    */

    //Add an event listener for when "links" on the menu are clicked and initialize SWFAddress
        private function init(event:FlexEvent):void {
        //Listen for menu clicks
            var skin:Theme = Theme(this.skin);
            this.menu = Menu(skin.menu);
            this.menu.addEventListener(Menu.MENU_ITEM_CLICKED, menuNavigateToPageHandler);

        //Initialize SWFAddress
            SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.INIT, initSWFAddress);
        }

    //Initialize SWFAddress and grab the page listed from the URL
        private function initSWFAddress(e:SWFAddressEvent):void {
        //Listen for change events
            SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, URLNavigateToPageHandler);

        //Fetch the page from the URL
            var URL:String = SWFAddress.getValue();

            if (URL == "" || URL == "/") {
                pagesResponder.token = page.getPagesByPosition(1);
            } else {
                pagesResponder.token = page.getPagesByURL(URL.substring(1));
            }
        }

    /**
     * Navigation handlers
     * -------------------------------
    */

    //Go to a specific page when a menu item has been clicked
        private function menuNavigateToPageHandler(e:MenuEvent):void {
            SWFAddress.setValue(e.pageURL);
            pagesResponder.token = page.getPagesByID(e.pageID);
        }

    //Request a page when the URL has changed
        private function URLNavigateToPageHandler(e:SWFAddressEvent):void {
            var URL:String = SWFAddress.getValue();

            if (URL == "" || URL == "/") {
                pagesResponder.token = page.getPagesByPosition(1);
            } else {
                pagesResponder.token = page.getPagesByURL(URL.substring(1));
            }
        }   

    /**
     * Loading content
     * -------------------------------
    */  

    //Show an error dialog in the case of an error when communicating with the server
        private function requestErrorHandler(e:FaultEvent):void {
            Alert.show("Fault string: " + e.fault.faultString + "\nFault detail: " + e.fault.faultDetail, e.fault.faultCode);
        }   

    //Determine what kind of page will be constructed
        private function determinePage(e:ResultEvent):void {
            var pageType:String = pagesResponder.lastResult.type;

        //We will need to know the type of page to build
            switch(pageType) {
                case "menu" : 
                    menuResponder.token = menuFetch.getMenuByType(pagesResponder.lastResult.category);
                    break;

                case "lunch" : 
                    break;

                case "reviews" : 
                    reviewsResponder.token = reviews.getAllReviews();
                    break;

                case "home" : 
                default : 
                    break;
            }
        }

    //Using the data that was fetched from the "menuFetch" service, construct the page of type menu
        private function constructMenu(e:ResultEvent):void {
        //Transition the existing page out of view
            if (this.pageObject != null) {
                Alert.show("i");
                TweenMax.to(this.pageObject, 0.75, {
                    alpha : 0,
                    y : 20
                });


                removeElement(this.pageObject);
            }

            setTimeout(function():void {
                this.pageObject = new FoodMenu();
                this.pageObject.alpha = 0;
                this.pageObject.y = 20;
                this.pageObject.data = menuResponder.lastResult;
                addElement(this.pageObject);

            //Tween the new menu into place
                TweenMax.to(this.pageObject, 0.75, {
                    alpha : 1,
                    y : 0
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<!-- Make a request to the server for the page data -->
<fx:Declarations>
    <pagesservice:PagesService id="page"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="pagesResponder" fault="requestErrorHandler(event)" result="determinePage(event)"/>

    <menuservice:MenuService id="menuFetch"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="menuResponder" fault="requestErrorHandler(event)" result="constructMenu(event)"/>

    <reviewsservice:ReviewsService id="reviews"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="reviewsResponder" fault="requestErrorHandler(event)" result="constructMenu(event)"/>
</fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: We can't tell you why pageObject always registers as not null unless we know how/when the constructMenu is called.  Also when is setTimeout called.  And how do they relate to other elements of the page?  You'll have to provide the complete component (MXML File) for us to help you more.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com The full MXML for the relevant application has been added.

Comment: I'm having trouble dissecting your code to figure out why stuff happens when it happens.  Perhaps you need to provide a smaller, complete, code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Thank you for looking at my code. Baris and Sunil were able to solve my problem below. I know my application can be a tad confusing, unless you can see the architecture of the database that powers it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible problem I see is with this piece of code :

```
setTimeout(function():void {
   this.pageObject = new FoodMenu(); //Should now be not-null!!!
   //Do more stuff with the FoodMenu() and add to the main application
}, 1000);
```

The "this" pointer refers to something else(possibly the global object) in the closure.

Try the following to see for your self :

```
trace(this);
setTimeout(function():void {
    trace(this);
},1000);
```

Comment: This is exactly what the problem is... Kind of a surprise, but I never use `setTimeout()`. Inside the anonymous function (declared in the call to `setTimeout()`) `this` is the global object, not the class the OP is expecting. The code will behave as expected **IF** you do not use an anonymous/inline function with `setTimeout()`, but just pass it a reference to a function that you declare in your class.

Comment: @SunilD. Really really weird, but good to know! I guess that this is one that that AS is different from JS! Let me try that out.